# Oneboxing Wikipedia section should quote the relevant part of the page

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

I was trying to link part of an article on wikipedia - specifically [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slot_1#Intel_440BX_.5B8.5D) to refer to a specific section of the wikipedia entry. It quotes start of the article, as opposed to the part of the article I was trying to link to - it was a little confusing.

[image: onebox - Chemistry]

*The onebox for [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemistry#Molecule)*

[image: actual section lnked]

*The section that the link actually points to.*

Note that the link still *works* - it takes you to the correct section. But, the onebox implies it will go to the top-level article instead, which is confusing.

So... could we get oneboxes to be aware of sections in pages - they do seem to use a standard notation.

Comment: It actually does link to the right place if you click it, but the onebox's text shows the beginning of the article

Comment: corrected. that's what i meant tho ;)